# JavaScript reading all 6 when 3 are hidden on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

My JavaScript function is reading all 6 total images and not 3 on mobile and 3 when desktop. My `hidden-mobile` and `hidden-desktop` CSS classes work totally fine and hide the images making the carousel scroll through all 6, showing three and other three blank. I'm very confused.

The HTML:

```
     <div class="parent hidden-mobile">
            <div class="mySlides fade image2">
                <img src="img/homebanner1.png" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade image2">
                <img src="img/homebanner2.png" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade image2">
                <img src="img/homebanner3.png" style="width:100%">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="parent hidden-desktop">
            <div class="mySlides fade image2">
                <img src="img/homebannermobile1.png" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade image2">
                <img src="img/homebannermobile2.png" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade image2">
                <img src="img/homebannermobile3.png" style="width:100%">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var slideIndex = 0;
    showSlides();
    function showSlides() {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for(i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slideIndex++;
        if(slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(showSlides, 10000); // Change image every 10 seconds
    }
```

Comment: You have to check for the `hidden-*` classes in your JavaScript.  Just because you mark something as hidden in HTML, that doesn't mean the JavaScript knows about that or will just do it.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I've never seen/heard of ```hidden-*``` before and google doesn't seem to show anything.

Comment: The `hidden-*` refers to your `hidden-mobile` and `hidden-desktop` CSS classes.  Your script doesn't know anything about them unless you tell it to.  In this case, you should probably check for the width and height of the screen, and select which images you want according to those checks.  In other words, see if `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` are within whatever range your CSS classes dictate, and only populate the carousel with the proper images based on that (which would be easier if they were stored in separate mobile and desktop directories).

Answer (score -2):

You can add a media query to you css which will hide three at a certain screen size:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .parent.hidden-desktop{
    display: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .parent.hidden-mobile{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

But you will need to add the class parent hidden-mobile like you did for the desktop with "parent hidden-desktop".

Comment: I already had that but was cropped out.

Comment: OP doesn't have `<hidden-mobile>` or `<hidden-desktop>` elements which are descendants of `.parent` (which your CSS selectors target).

Comment: @connexo rather than complaining about others answers, why don't you provide some help of your own.

Comment: You prefer mistakes in your answers to not be pointed out?